# Is infinite looping on firebase onSnapshot function normal?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I have a chunk of code that listens when a new page is added to Cloud Firestore database. Basically, it uses onSnapshot event listener for this.

I use React hooks to store what's coming from the DB. What I have noticed, is when I use the `setPages(tmp_array)`, the `PRINT THIS` keeps on being printed, which make me think of an infinite loop, but the website isn't slowed at all. When the `setPages(tmp_array)` is commented, it's only printed once, as I think it should be. But I do need to store the data in an array! FYI, pages, excepted on this useEffect, isn't used anywhere else, and I don't use setPages, except here, so the data isn't "new" every time.

```
const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);

const eventPageListener = pagesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    console.log('PRINT THIS');
    setPages(snapshot.docChanges().filter(change => change.type === 'added').map(change => change.doc.data()));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pages.length > 0) {
      eventPageListener();
    }
  }, [pages]);
```

Is the excepted behaviour an infinite loop ? As it's the first time I'm using a listener, I'm not quite sure. Won't that slow down the website in the end, if it's being called every time ? I also notice that unsubscribing doesn't work. I really feel like I'm doing something wrong here..

Comment: What does setPages do?  Please edit the question to help us understand everything in the code path.

Comment: It's using the useState hook (look at the first line). It's used to set an array of objects. The array will then be available in `pages`

Comment: I see where you're defining it.  I'm curious about the implementation of that function.  Did you author it, or are you saying it's built into the framework (I don't know how react works)?

Comment: It's actually build into the framework (See here for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Comment: If `setPages` somehow causes the contents of the database anywhere under `pagesRef` to change, the snapshot listener will get invoked with that change.  That would cause a circular reference.

Comment: I agree, tho setPages doesn't push or update any content on the DB. Even when I print the number of records in that array, it's still the same number, with the same data

Comment: same here. did you solve this? just started react+firestore db.collection('products').onSnapshot(snapshot => getting called relentlessly

Comment: @Fakeer If I remember well, I dropped this project soon after, but I assumed it was the correct behaviour. Looking at your answer below, did the Listener still worked? If so, that's nice!

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to emulate the `componentDidMount` behavior which will be only called once, you can try an empty array with `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pages.length > 0) {
      eventPageListener();
    }
  }, []); // instead of [pages]
```

In my case using `[]` stopped the infinite loop